# Capacitive impedance

Tags: capacitor, impedance

When one wants to give an easy explanation to a simple RC low pass filter, one states that at low frequencies Zc is almost infinite, so similar to an open circuit thus the signal can go, while at high frequencies Zc is almost zero, so similar to a short circuit and the signal goes to ground without being transmitted.

My question is: can I apply the same reasoning to Zc but in terms of C and not frequency? In the denominator of Zc I have the product of omega and C: can I say that for very low values of C, Zc is like an open circuit, and for very high values of C, it is like a short circuit? That is, exactly the same reasoning usually done with omega, but with C instead.

Comment: I'm going to +1 this question. It's the kind of thing all of us go through, in one way or another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The magnitude of a capacitive impedance is

|Zc|=1/wC.

If you increase the product wC by a factor of 10 the impedance will be reduced by the same factor. It does not matter at all if you increase w (C constant) or C (w constant).

Answer (score 2):

Well, notice that the transfer function of a low-pass RC filter is given by:

$$\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right):=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{o}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\text{sC}}}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\text{sC}}+\text{R}}=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle1+\text{sCR}}\tag1$$

So, we get:

$$\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\sqrt{1+\left(\omega\text{CR}\right)^2}}\tag2$$

So, we can see that when \$\displaystyle\omega\text{CR}\to0\$ we get \$\displaystyle\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=1\$ and when \$\displaystyle\omega\text{CR}\to\infty\$ we get \$\displaystyle\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=0\$.

> So, yes you can say that.

Answer (score 2):

The impedance of a capacitor is $$ Z_c=\frac{1}{j\omega C} $$
So you are correct, \$\omega\$ and \$C\$ are interchangeable.

For example:

- at 10kHz, a 1\$\mu\$F capacitor has an impedance of about 16\$\Omega\$ *(and 90º phase shift)*
- at double the frequency (20kHz) the same capacitor has half the impedance (8\$\Omega\$)
- at the original frequency (10kHz) but double the capacitance (2\$\mu\$F), the impedance is also \$\approx8\Omega\$

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the voltage across a capacitor is q/C: the stored charge divided by the capacitance.  Think about what the behavior of this circuit would be if C were tiny, femto- or atto-farads.  Just a few electrons move onto the top plate and it's instantly "full".  No more current can flow into it, so there's no additional current that needs to flow through R to charge it up.  Now imagine if C were huge; adding additional electrons will barely change the voltage across the capacitor so if one end is connected to ground, the other end which is connected to the output will require a lot of charge (which takes a lot of time) to change its voltage even a little bit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDp16o.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>